# django framework: null value in column "hardware_type" violates not-null constraint

Tags: python, angular, django-rest-framework

I know there are solutions to this problem on Stack overflow but they do not seem to work in my case.

The following is my code:

models.py

```
hardware_used = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
cores_used = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

admin.py

```
@admin.register(Run)
class RunAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ('sub_project', 'name', 'status')
list_filter = ('sub_project__project__account', )
fields = ('sub_project', 'name', 'description', 'status', 'input_zip', 
'output_zip', 'metadata', 'hardware_used', 'cores_used')
```

0010_auto_20190125_1513.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.11.15 on 2019-01-25 15:13
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
    ('simulations', '0009_auto_20190125_1506'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='run',
        name='hardware_used',
        field=models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20, null=True),
    ),
]
```

Whatever combination of blank=True or null=True I use give me the same error when i try to post some data.

> django framework: null value in column "hardware_type" violates not-null constraint

Any idea, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add default value

```
hardware_used = models.CharField(default='some_hardware')
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is `hardware_type` field? Make sure you are defined that.

If you just run `python.x manage.py makemigrations`. You need to run `python.x manage.py migrate` to apply new migration

Comment: Oh my God, I did not notice it! The system is complaining about hardware_type that was the old name of the field changed into hardware-used. Something must be wrong somewhere. I will investigate. Well spotted!

Comment: If you cannot find the root cause. You can try to access database and delete this field in that table